# Most efficient file type for random data access

Tags: c++, file-io

I am writing a password generation program. I have collected a list of around 30,000 English words and plan on picking from them at random by index.

Currently, I have all the words in a .txt file each separated by a newline character and organized by length.

My current plan is to write the program in C++ because that is the language I am most comfortable in so I could just load the entire file into memory, but that seems incredibly sloppy.

What would be a more efficient way (or file type like JSON if necessary) to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you concidereed the EFF's diceware password list: https://www.eff.org/dice It has a built in index in base6 which can easily be looked up.

Comment: I agree with others, spend your time elsewhere than caring about a few Mb. You can even embed it as a resource. Encrypted even

Comment: @Sukima I had not heard of that site. My program will work very similarly, except it will also add in numbers and characters at random to increase the complexity. I also have limited the words to be 6 characters or less which that site does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

30,000 words sounds like an insignificant amount of data to load. Even if it's ~50-500MB just load it in and forget about it.

On a modern system this will take a fraction of a second to accomplish the first time, any SSD can do ~600MB/s+, and even less once it's in the OS disk buffer.

You'd only concern yourself with not loading it if you've got a file too big to fit in memory.

Comment: Besides any file format designed for optimized random access would explode in size as you would have to have byte offsets known before reading padding every entry to a fixed size. It is not worth it for the exceptionally small improvement over reading the full set into memory.

Comment: @Sukima One wouldn't make the strings a fixed lengths, one would make an index.

Comment: @Sukima It's a very basic principle. If you have variable length fields you need to create an index. This is often done with a BTree.

Comment: @Sukima: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_file. The index is just an offset in the file of the start of each piece of data.  If your data is 30k strings, then you'd have an index of 30k integer offsets.  To access string #12345, you look at integer #12345, and if that says the offset is 654321, then you seek to location 654321 in the file, and read the string.  O(1) time.  This works _very_ well with memory mapped files, because then the OS doesn't have to keep the file in memory the whole time.